# Is it possible to cast two 9th-level spells without taking a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, rests

The 9th-level spell [*foresight*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/foresight) says that the spell immediately ends if you cast it again before the duration is up. However, the spell's duration is 8 hours.

I get that you could cast it a second time before the duration was up if you are an elf who finishes a long rest in 4 hours or something like that.

However, is there any official way to cast more than one 9th-level spell without taking a long rest?

Comment: It might be worth noting, with regards to Foresight's duration, if you had the Extended Spell Metamagic from a Sorcerer multiclass for example, you could double the duration up to a maximum of 24 hours and take a long rest within that time frame to cast it twice.

Comment: @DucksGoMooful Note that RAI is that you can only double the duration of Foresight once via Extended Spell per casting. Crawford has [stated](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/629527321569988608) "The intent is that a sorcerer can use a Metamagic option once with a spell, not the same option more than once." So its duration would only become 16 hours (long enough to take a long rest during it, but not as long as previously stated).

Answer (score 31):

### Spell Scrolls<sup>1</sup>

Provided you obtain enough of them and have enough time to cast them all, using 9th level [spell scrolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) would allow one to cast a lot of 9th level spells without a long rest.

### Epic Boons

The DMG has rules for granting epic boons (starting on page 231) that include:

> **Boon of High Magic**
>
> You gain one 9th-level spell slot, provided that you already have one.
>
> **Boon of spell recall**
>
> You can cast any spell you know or have prepared without expending a spell slot. Once you do so, you can't use this boon again until you finish a long rest.

Either of these boons would allow one to cast Foresight (or another 9th level spell) twice before taking a long rest.

### Monsters

Monsters do not have the same restrictions as player characters and it is also possible for them to have more than one 9th level spell slot. An example of this in published adventures is (spoilers):

> [Acererak](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/acererak) from Tomb of Anihilation

---

1. Suggested by [NautArch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/23024/nautarch)

Answer (score 21):

## A number of magic items can let you do this

I'm not going to go full detail on, the key is all of these let the user (that's you good citizen) cast a 9th level spell without spending a spell slot. Yes, the list is quite legendary item/artifact heavy. (Numbers in parenthesis give page number for the *Dungeon Master's Guide*.)

- 9th level spell scrolls obviously let you cast whatever 9th level spell was inscribed in them.
- Candle of Invocation (157) and Cubic Gate (160) both allow the casting of *gate*.
- Luck Blade (179), Ring of Three Wishes (193), and the Moon card from Deck of Many Things (162) let's you cast *wish*. Also, if you have both the Eye and Hand of Vecna (224)(no downsides, promise) you can cast *wish* once per 30 days.
- Wand of Orcus (227) lets you cast *power word kill*. I would recommend being Orcus or having his blessing, then it only cost you 2 of its 7 charges.
- Wand of Fireballs (210) and Wand of Lighting bolt (211) allow you to, by spending all of the charges at once, to cast *fire ball* and *lightning bolt* as 9th level spells respectively.
- Tome of the Stilled Tongue (208) lets cast any spell you have written in it for free as a bonus action. Only downside is Vecna is writing notes in your spellbook, but I'm sure those are notes of encouragements.
- Book of Exalted Deeds (222) has the neat effect of making all your Cleric and Paladin spells count as one level higher. Thus you can cast a 8th level Cleric spell as a 9th level spell.

## Epic Boons

- Boon of High Magic (232) gives you a second 9th level spell slot, which lets you cast any 9th level spell you have prepared.
- Boon of Spell Recall (232) lets you cast a prepared spell without expending a spell slot.

## Be one of certain, high CR monsters

There are a few monsters which can cast multiple 9th level spells per day. Either through having multiple spell slots or having multiple 9th level spells as 1/day:

- > [Sul Khatesh](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sul-khatesh)

- > [Bel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bel)

- > [Acerak](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/acererak)

- > [Ygorl, Lord of Entropy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ygorl-lord-of-entropy)

Comment: *Only downside is Vecna is writing notes in your spellbook, but I'm sure those are notes of encouragements*  nicely done . (Chuckles)

Answer (score -1):

If your DM prefers to use the Epic Heroism rest variant (DMG pg 267), a long rest takes only one hour.